# Banned words filter (tmi.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

So I've been trying to make this work for about 3 hours now, and I' almost giving up.

My current code is:

```js
var tmi = require('tmi.js');

var linksDisallowed = ["http://", "https://", ".dk"];

var options = {
 options: {
  debug: true
 },
 connection: {
  cluster: "aws",
  reconnect: true
 },
 identity: {
  username: "botstormen",
  password: "**CENSORED FOR SECURITY REASONS**"
 },
 channels: ["dunkstormen"]
};

var client = new tmi.client(options);
client.connect();

client.on('connected', function(adress, port) {
 client.action("dunkstormen", "joinede chatten og er klar til at hjælpe! :3");
});

client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
 if(message === "!social" || message === "!Social") {
  client.action("dunkstormen", "Twitter: twitter.com/dunkstormen Facebook: facebook.com/dunkstormen");
 }
});

client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  
  if(message.indexOf(linksDisallowed[i]) >= 0) {
   client.say("Hello, " + user);
  }
  
 }
});
```

But whenever I type one of the word in the array linksDisallowed into the chat the bot just instantly crashes with the following error:

```html
C:\Users\Benjamin Jørgensen\Desktop\botstormen\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\commands.js:207
        if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith("/me ") || message.toLowerCase().startsWith("\\me ")) {
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at client.say (C:\Users\Benjamin Jørgensen\Desktop\botstormen\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\commands.js:207:20)
    at client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Benjamin Jørgensen\Desktop\botstormen\app.js:37:11)
    at client.EventEmitter.emit (C:\Users\Benjamin Jørgensen\Desktop\botstormen\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\events.js:99:50)
    at client.handleMessage (C:\Users\Benjamin Jørgensen\Desktop\botstormen\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\client.js:792:34)
    at C:\Users\Benjamin Jørgensen\Desktop\botstormen\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\client.js:919:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at client._onMessage (C:\Users\Benjamin Jørgensen\Desktop\botstormen\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\client.js:917:11)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Benjamin Jørgensen\Desktop\botstormen\node_modules\tmi.js\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:442:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:172:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tmi.js command `say` takes 2 arguments, you are passing only one.

https://docs.tmijs.org/v0.0.29/Commands.html#say

Change `client.say("Hello, " + user);` to `client.say(channel,"Hello, " + user);`

EDIT to help about comment:

According to docs, https://docs.tmijs.org/v0.0.29/Events.html#chat the chat event returns a user object. There is the description of a user object just below with a notice about it can change... But you can certainly do this for now: replace `user` by `user.username` .

If it does not work, inspect the user object to find the right property you should use.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have the issue that user just returns [object Object] instead of the users actual name.

Comment: Edited. BTW, I have never used tmijs or twitch... Just reading the doc :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

That would mean your `app.js` isn't sending a message into the tmi.js service